# HTML How do I put my variables into the paragraphs as text?

Tags: html

I have variables labelled $name, $phone, and $totalCost. I want to put them into a paragraph , but I'm not sure how to. Is there a way to break the paragraph just for a few words?
Amendment: sorry, realized that I didn't post any code to show my problem.

snippet:

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $totalCost = $_POST['totalCost'];
 $subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];

<p>Thank you ($name) at ($phone).  Details of your total cost of $.number_format($totalCost, 2) are shown below:</p>
```

This prints: "Thank you ($name) at $phone). Details of your total cost of $.number_format($totalCost, 2) are shown below:"

With no numbers being placed in the spaces for the variables, instead it prints the $name, $phone, and $.number_format($totalCost, 2).

Comment: See example entry below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the paragraph tags around your text:

```
<p> $name </p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate the contents of the paragraph, so this is just a guess.

```
    let str = `We have created a tag for ${$name} with the phone number of ${$phone}.
    The total cost will be: ${$totalCost}.`;
```

Write the above as a Template Literal statement with JS like:

document.getElementById('elemName').innerHTML = str;

where 'elemName' is the ID value of a paragraph like:
<p id='elemName'></p>
located somewhere in your HTML page.

Comment: When I try that, it puts the $name into text and not the actual information the variable has.

Comment: You did not enter the variables into the template literal correctly. Note the extra ${ } surrounding the variables ($name, $phone, etc.)  See the example above.